# Simple facts about generators of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

There are a couple of simple facts about generators of groups which seem intuitively plausible but which I'm not sure how to establish rigorously. (They emerged from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818948/quotients-of-order-24-of-a-free-abelian-group) question.)

If a group $G$ cannot be generated by $n$ elements, how do I show that $G\times H$ also cannot be generated by $n$ elements? And if a group $G$ is generated by $n$ elements, how do I show that its quotient is also generated by $n$ elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $G \times H$ is generated by $n$ elements $\{(g_1, h_1), \cdots, (g_n, h_n)\}$, then $g_1, \cdots, g_n$ generate $G$.

---

If $G$ is generated by $g_1, \cdots, g_n$, then for any normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, $G/N$ is generated by $g_1 N, \cdots, g_n N$.

Comment: The first fact is a particular case of the second one.

Comment: @YCor Why? [Additional symbols since Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.]

Comment: @user437307 $G = (G \times H) / H$