# Characterize Abelian Factor Group to Direct Product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, finitely-generated, direct-product

> What group is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_8)/\langle(1,2,4)\rangle$?

I can only see that $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_8$ has $128$ elements and $\langle(1,2,4)\rangle$ has $4$ elements, so this factor group will have $128/4=32$ elements, and will therefore be isomorphic to exactly one of the following groups:
$$
\mathbb{Z}_{32},
\quad
\mathbb{Z}_{16}\times\mathbb{Z}_2,
\quad
\mathbb{Z}_8\times\mathbb{Z}_4, 
\quad
\mathbb{Z}_8\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2,
\quad
\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2
$$

However, determining which one it is actually isomorphic to seems like a messy work, I can only do it by writing all the cosets and see which abelian group it is isomorphic to. Is there any faster and reliable method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in detail [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2798465) you need to find the Smith normal form of the matrix $$\pmatrix{4&0&0\\0&4&0\\0&0&8\\1&2&4}$$
First, use the $1$ in the bottom-left to get rid of the last row and first column:
$$\pmatrix{4&0&0\\0&4&0\\0&0&8\\1&2&4}\to\pmatrix{4&-8&-16\\0&4&0\\0&0&8\\1&0&0}\to\pmatrix{\color{red}0&-8&-16\\\color{red}0&4&0\\\color{red}0&0&8\\\color{red}1&\color{red}0&\color{red}0}$$
The isolated $1$ corresponds to a factor $\Bbb Z/1\Bbb Z$ which is the trivial group, so we forget about it. We proceed with the remaining $3\times 2$ matrix
$$\pmatrix{-8&-16\\4&0\\0&8}\to \pmatrix{\color{red}0&-16\\\color{red}4&\color{red}0\\\color{red}0&8}$$
where a factor $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ splits out.

Finally $$\pmatrix{-16\\8}\to\pmatrix{0\\8}$$ gives you the last factor, $\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$. Hence the quotient is isomorphic to: $$\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$$

Comment: Wow, seems like a new method for me. I will research a little more on this topic, thanks!

Comment: @kelvin You're welcome.